# Get Carriage return for incoming data on teraterm using C++

Tags: c++, serial-port, stm32, teraterm

I am using a STM32 and communicating with it through the serial port. I have a lot of data that I receive. I am using TeraTerm for my project. 
So I get my continuous data on a new line and I do not want that. I want it to re-write the output on the same line. In this way I wont have to see the entire list but just one line with updated values. I tried using just '\r' in the print statement but it behaves the same way. 
Is there any teraterm setting for Carriage Return that could help me with what I want?

My output looks likes this:

*act-

150.00  4.09    -0.83

150.00  4.09    -0.83

150.00  4.09    -0.83

150.00  4.09    -0.83

150.00  4.09    -0.83

Code:

```
bool IOParser::ACT(bool print_help)
{
  if (print_help)
  {
      uart_printf("\nDisplay xxx");

  }
  else
  {
      uart_printf("\r%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f", x, y, z);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I just want to know how to get CR without the new data generating new lines. Thank you!

Comment: I couln't find any documentation regarding `uart_printf`, only on `UART_printf`. I looked at what I think is the [source code](https://github.com/afiskon/stm32-r820t2/blob/master/Src/main.c) for that function, and that does not add `\n` to the strings. I doubt teraterm adds newlines either. How would it know where to add them? It only receives a stream of characters.